# For a given value in a cell, which, if any, of a set of pairs of cells is that value between

Tags: excel-formula

Say I have a column of values, maybe visitor arrival dates, and a pair of columns, maybe start and end dates of holidays, how can I find which arrival dates occur between which holiday pairs?

For example:

Value
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13

Lower   Upper

5 8

9 10

8   11

9   12

So from the value list, 7 is in the pair (5,8)

Comment: what would you like the output to return? the row number? The cell address? the range as text?

Comment: The row number of the range, in this case the row number of (5, 8) would be great.

Comment: What would you expect the number 9 to return then? the row of (9,10), (8,11) or (9,12)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your lower and upper values are actually holiday dates, then if you're talking about one particular country they shouldn't overlap and you would only want to find a match with one of them.

In that case this formula should do it (entered as an array formula with Ctr-Shift-Enter), but if there is more than one matching row it will just show the last one:-

=MAX((A2>=D$2:D$5)*(A2<=E$2:E$5)*ROW(D$2:D$5))

[image]